# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have looked at other posts here on this topic and not found a clear answer, though I'm sure its something simple.

My code has the following structure...

```
import matplotlib
...
...

class xyz:
    def function_A(self,...)
        ...
        ...
        fig1 = matplotlib.figure()
        ...
        ...
```

I am calling 'function_A' from an instance of 'xyz' and when I do I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'figure'
```

Based on the posts I have read it seems like a problem with the way I'm importing matplotlib, but I can't sort it out. I have tried importing it within the Function_A definition (I think that is bad form but I wanted to test it), but I still the the same error.

I have used my 'function_A' code elsewhere with no problem, but it was just a function in a module, not a method in a class.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you're right and it's an import issue.  The `matplotlib` module doesn't *have* a `figure` function:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.figure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-130-82eb15b3daba>", line 1, in <module>
    matplotlib.figure
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'figure'
```

The figure function is located deeper.  There are a few ways to pull it in, but the usual import looks more like:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.figure
<function figure at 0xb2041ec>
```

It's probably a good idea to stick to this custom, because it's used by the majority of examples you'll find on the Web, such as those in the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html).  (The gallery is is still the first place I go to when I need to figure out how to do something: I find an image which looks like what I want, and then look at the code.)

Comment: Jesus Christ, I'm an idiot. My other code correctly imports the module. Thanks for the help.